# IBM Integration bus, parsing json

Tags: java, json, integration

Hello I have a problem to parse any `JSON` in `IIB` Toolkit. The exception thrown by java compute node is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.JSONObject`

I am parsing incoming `JSON` messages in `UTF-8`. I already tried to get them in `JSON`, but accepting them as `BLOB` and converting to `JSON UTF-8` works for me.

```
String messageText = new String(outMessage.getRootElement().getLastChild().getLastChild().getValueAsString());
messageText = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(messageText),"UTF-8");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{}");
```

I would love to create `JSON` object from `JSON` string in `UTF-8`

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is a bit of a no-no. You're trying to use the Java class JSONObject rather than using the builtin IIB Java Parser.

Have a look at [MbElement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.plugin.doc/com/ibm/broker/plugin/MbElement.html) in particular the methods createElementAsLastChild(java.lang.String parserName) and createElementAsLastChildFromBitstream.

As per my earlier answer never forget your are trying to build a tree of elements.

One other trick I sometimes use is to build a sample **output** message and send it to an Input node connected to a Trace node. I then use the Trace node output to write code to build my actual output tree, you can even put a Trace node after your JavaCompute node to see what the Element tree you've currently built looks like and correct your mistakes. I mostly use this method for SOAP messages which can be quite complex.

If you really want to use external Java classes then search for [Using JAXB with a JavaCompute node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac49010_.htm) and follow the links from that article.